# Return MongoDB collection with AWS Lambda and API Gateway

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a function in AWS Lambda written in Python.

I am trying to extract documents from a collection in MongoDB with `pymongo`.

I thought it was quite simple, but I seem to get problems (maybe because of ObjectID types).

I am simply trying to do

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

def lambda_handler(event, context):

  client = MongoClient(MONGODB_URI)

  db = client[DB_NAME]

  return db.users.find({})
```

but I get the error

```
{errorMessage= is not JSON serializable, errorType=TypeError, stackTrace=[["\/var\/lang\/lib\/python3.6\/json\/__init__.py",238,"dumps","**kw).encode(obj)"],["\/var\/lang\/lib\/python3.6\/json\/encoder.py",199,"encode","chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)"],["\/var\/lang\/lib\/python3.6\/json\/encoder.py",257,"iterencode","return _iterencode(o, 0)"],["\/var\/runtime\/awslambda\/bootstrap.py",110,"decimal_serializer","raise TypeError(repr(o) + \" is not JSON serializable\")"]]}
```

It does work if I use `return bson.json_util.dumps(db.users.find({}))`, but why should it be necessary?

As far as I understand, lambda functions always return json, so I don't understand why I have to use `bson.json_util`.

Also, when I use this function, I don't get normal ObjectID types, but instead I get

```
[
  {"_id": {"$oid": "59aed327f25c0f0ca8f94ae1"}, "name": ...},
  ...
]
```

although I wanted something like

```
[
  {"_id": "59aed327f25c0f0ca8f94ae1", "name": ...},
  ...
]
```

Comment: Can you share your script where you have connected to MongoDB and are getting or posting data to it using AWS Lambda? I keep running into issues and I am not able to get anything done on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is due to pymongo not returning straight JSON strings. An example of how to handle this can be found here -

[How do I turn MongoDB query into a JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404742/how-do-i-turn-mongodb-query-into-a-json)

It should be noted that API Gateway expects to return JSON unless configured otherwise. 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/